# For loop to loop through files

Tags: python, loops

I have the code below and it works like I want it to. The only thing I want to change to it is to add a for loop. Pay attention to this line please:

```
 node = import_file("../Angle1/1eV/cascade.dump",multiple_frames = True)
```

Notice the 1eV in there. I want to loop from 1 to 10eV. How can I insert a for loop to go from 1 to 100 eV like this so that I don't have to manually right it out which will take a while?

```
# Import OVITO modules.
from ovito.io import *
from ovito.modifiers import *

# Import NumPy module.
import numpy
import sys



node = import_file("../Angle1/1eV/cascade.dump",multiple_frames = True)
ovito.dataset.anim.current_frame = 1

mod = WignerSeitzAnalysisModifier(per_type_occupancies = True)
mod.reference.load("position_perfect_300.dump")
node.modifiers.append(mod)
node.compute()
node.modifiers.append(SelectExpressionModifier(expression = 'ParticleType==1 && Occupancy.1==0 && Occupancy.2==0'))
node.compute()

f=open("1.out",'w')
sys.stdout = f


print("Number of O vacant sites: %i" % numpy.count_nonzero(node.output.particle_properties['Selection']))

f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: just make your loop start like this, then keep the same indentation incuding your final `print` statement (that I changed so it doesn't override `sys.stdout`, and I open the file *before* the loop so messages don't get overwritten):

```
with open("1.out",'w') as f:

    for i in range(1,11):
        node = import_file("../Angle1/{}eV/cascade.dump".format(i),multiple_frames = True)
        ovito.dataset.anim.current_frame = 1

        mod = WignerSeitzAnalysisModifier(per_type_occupancies = True)
        mod.reference.load("position_perfect_300.dump")
        node.modifiers.append(mod)
        node.compute()
        node.modifiers.append(SelectExpressionModifier(expression = 'ParticleType==1 && Occupancy.1==0 && Occupancy.2==0'))
        node.compute()

        f.write("Number of O vacant sites: %i\n" % numpy.count_nonzero(node.output.particle_properties['Selection']))
```

Comment: How do you end the for statement to make it loop back? If it is already doing that then I think my print statement is getting overwritten every time

Comment: I need to loop through once I carried out the commands below and write to my file. I should have several things in my file at the end. Does it know to carry out the commands below before moving on to the next file? I feel like the way it is currently set up, it just loads all my files and calculates the last one but I'm not sure.

Comment: check my edit. Indentation is crucial in python, I hope you know that.

Comment: Maybe you should copy and paste the whole thing including the parts of the code that I already had that are required - The only reason I say this is I tried using yours by putting it into part of my code, but it still seems to overwrite, unless I am removing something critical. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: If I copy paste your code after my sys/stdout = f part, then it still overwrites, so I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Of course! the overwrite is expected. I moved the open _before_ the loop. Sorry, it's late :)

Comment: Sorry I got it working! Thanks for your help! this really helps me a lot!

Comment: My pleasure. I almost refused to answer that because I thought it was too trivial, but the logfile within the loop was a nice touch :)

Comment: Can I ask 1 follow up question? If I want to also make the Angle1 actually be a loop as well from 1 to 24, would I do the same thing and have .format(i).format(j) or something? Actually that may be getting too complicated. I would then need 24 columns as well and not just a single column

Comment: That may be too complicated actually - I would need it to format it as 24 columns of data as well. I will just make a new post with that question so it does not take away from the question here.

Comment: Just work on it, and post a different question for the format issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130261/discussion-between-jackson-hart-and-jean-francois-fabre).

Comment: I noticed 1 thing wrong with the script. It does 1 less that what I request. Is there some indexing I need to be aware of? If I choose range, 1,5 I get 4 values as opposed to 5.

Comment: I wish I had noticed this earlier. Seems like 1 value is missing every time no matter the range I do.